# Calculating and tracking benefits post delivery

Tags: tracking, budget

Prior to commencing a project we need to justify taking on the project by detailing expected benefits. To date their is no follow up on this information, no way to monitor and no way to calculate benefits.

How can we implement a program to successfully track and calculate benefits post delivery when benefits are varied (e.g compare a web project to an infrastructure project to a BI project) and may only be realised over an extended period.

Comment: What is your organizational policy for calculating this information? If you're required to do it, there should be a documented procedure or methodology.

Comment: Why are you considering doing the project? There must be a justification for it? Broadly speaking those are the expected benefits. Look at what  cost/benefit analysis (aka. business case) is, which should detail the expected benefits in more detail. When you know what the benefits are, then you can work out how to measure whether the project delivers those benefits. Note though, that the measurement of benefits realisation is not usually a responsibility of the project, only the setting up of the measurement processes. The project is usually over by the time benefits realisation is measured

Answer (score 2):

This starts with your business case. In that document you should have documented all of the benefits that you expect to accrue and that justify the money to be spent on the project. Integrated with your business case is a benefits realization plan, which documents the benefit to be accrued, who is accountable for accruing it, the metric(s) used to measure this accrual, the frequency of measurement, and what the targets are that define success. **If a benefit cannot be measured it should not be in your business case.**

What you need to make this a success is buy-in and accountability from your management.  For example, if a benefit is reduced effort and therefore headcount the person who owns the staffing budget for that unit has to be accountable for achieving that reduction. Beyond that, you also need clear ownership of the process of assessing benefits, specifically someone in your organization who is not in a conflict of interest in terms of benefits realization.